# Raspberry pi ssh connect to remote server

Tags: ssh, remote, terminal

I have a remote cloud server (accessible only through ssh), with preexisting private and public keys, and I want to connect to it with my raspberry pi 3. I have already moved the private key over to my pi. How would I be able to connect using the default ssh terminal command? I am not familiar with the command, and I am stuck at something of the following:

```
ssh myuser@123.456.78.90 privatekey.key
```

I have the key file in the same directory that the command is executing in.

Comment: Welcome -- the ssh implementation on RpiOS (openSSH) is in much wider use than just on the Pi and has been around much longer; it is the same implementation usually used on other linux variants. Hence, it is already widely documented online (and in `man ssh`, accessible from the commandline). If for some reason you still cannot figure out how to do what you want, direct your questions to our larger sibling site, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). The switch for the key for is `-i`; you can  also specify these per host/IP in `~/.ssh/config` (see `man ssh_config`).

Comment: would `ssh-copy-id myuser@123.456.78.90` help? this will prompt you for password, and next time you can access the remote host without entering the password.

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

There seems a misconception about how `ssh` works. You should not have copied the *private* key from the server to the Pi, but the *public* key. Also, keys are normally stored in `~/.ssh`, and not in the directory that the command is executed in.

Normally, both hosts have two kind of key pairs,

- one for the server
- one for the user

The server keys are handled more or less automatically. You will see a message like 'identity cannot be verified, are you sure that the host is indeed the host that you want', or an error in the host keys of the server have been changed, but that is mostly all.

A user generates a public and private key-pair on the client with `ssh-keygen`. With all standard, this will result in a `id_rsa` and a `id_rsa.pub` in `~/.ssh`. The `id_rsa` contains the *private* key, and you should **never** allow anyone to see it, and certainly not copy it to another computer.

The `id_rsa.pub` contains the *public* key. Being public, you may transfer it to other  systems. You would typically append the public key to the file  `authorized_keys` in the `~/.ssh`-directory on the server.